# Next-Auth.js problem with Twitter Authorization

Tags: twitter, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to configure my web app to login via various social medias. I am using next and next-auth. I have gotten connection with Github through Next-Auth to work. However, Twitter is giving me issues. When I was using Twitter API v1.1 I was receiving a 302 error. I have specified to use Twitter API v2, and now upon login, I get the following message:[Twitter error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owudc.png)

Here are my Twitter developer portal settings:
[Twitter dev portal settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cipDi.png)
I have tried the callback url as both http://localhost:3000/api... and http://127.0.0.1/api... as suggested here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/apps/callback-urls

_app.tsx:
[_app.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waSSj.png)

[...nextauth].js:[...nextauth.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1SAF.png)

.env.local: [.env.local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Vdr.png)

signin.tsx: [signin.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atVhI.png)

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2):

This error means that you didn't give your app permission. Make use of your Twitter `APIKEY` and `API SECRET` provided by Twitter on your developer dashboard. Quick access: https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps.
Save your credentials in a `.env` file and use it on ur [...nextauth].js file.

```
 export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
      TwitterProvider({
        clientId: TWITTER_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET,
       }),
     ],

  secret: NEXT_SECRET,
})
```

Comment: Perhaps I am not following... I did get the Twitter API Key and API Secret from twitter, pasted into .env.local, and then used in [...nextauth].js under the Twitter provider. Images of all of that should be provided (but the key was cut off for security)

Comment: For oauth1, actually the client_id and client_secret are access token and secret.